# How to add floating button in PDF?

Tags: pdf, floating

I would like to add a floating button in PDF. However, after doing a lot research on internet, I didn't find any answers.

I would like the button to float/move across the pages with the scroll bar as the document is scrolled. Is there a way to implement it in PDF?

Note: I would prefer to not to use JavaScript to implement it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not possible in normal PDF without JavaScript.

Comment: Why would you prefer to not use JavaSript? What is it that you are trying to accomplish by having a button move as the user scrolls?

Comment: The reason for not using the JavaScript is that if the user has disabled the JavaScript the functionality won't work.

Answer (score 0):

As @mkl commented, it is not possible to add a floating button in PDF without using JavaScript.

PDF is meant to be used for fixed layout and not dynamically change as it is being viewed.

The closest I could find to what you are looking to do is [this](http://khkonsulting.com/2014/07/floating-text-pdf-documents/) article about creating text that shows/hides depending on where the cursor is. I can't think of a way to leverage this though to change the position of a button as a user scrolls and even then you would most likely run into different PDF viewers handling it differently.

Comment: Yeah, I have already thought about setting it to show/hide but that is not exactly what I want. The functionality that I want to implement is a floating button that can move with the scroll-bar, just like the way popup comment works in PDF.

Comment: I want to implement something like the button (up arrow) that appears at the bottom right corner in the following link when you scroll... it may not have the same functionality but it needs to float like that ...

http://html-tuts.com/demo/back-to-top/